# Issue Passing Value that Needs to be Printed

Tags: javascript, material-ui, pass-by-value

I want to call a function with 3 inputs. 2 of them are numbers and one is a string. The two numbers are further passed but that is not the issue. I want the string to be printed within the element.

I believe that this is an issue is with passing the parameter to an html part of the code but I don't know how to do it.

```
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';    


export function myfunction(name, min max){
    const midpoint = Math.ceil((min + max)/2)
    return(
    <div>
        <Typography id="input-slider">
            name //this is where I want name to be
        </Typography>
    <div/>
    )
}
```

In a second file I call this

```
function main(){
    return(
        <div>
            {myfunction(MYNAME, 0, 10)
        <div/>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining a function `myFunction` which is a react component. A react component is basically just a function that accepts a properties object as first argument and returns JSX (html for react).

The first little stone on your way to success here is that you accept three arguments in the `myFunction` function.

So here is how a correct react component could look like

```js
function MyAwesomeComponent({ name, min, max }) {
  const midpoint = Math.ceil((min + max) / 2);
  // use curly brackets around a variable as in {midpoint} to print the value
  return <Typography id='input-slider'>{name}</Typography>;
}
```

If we want to use it in another react component, as you do with the `main` function. Write is as a react component as well.

```js
function Main() {
  return <MyAwesomeComponent name={'YourName'} min={0} max={10} />;
}
```

I hope this solves your issue. For a better understanding of how to write react components I can highly recommend to read more in detail about this topic in the [official react documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html).

Answer (score -1):

I believe in order to pass the parameter within the html tags you want to use use a template literal. So your code would look like

```js
export function myfunction(name, min max){
    const midpoint = Math.ceil((min + max)/2)
    return(
    <div>
        <Typography id="input-slider">
            ${name}
        </Typography>
    <div/>
    )
}
```